# How to get 2 distinct rows from 1 row with 3 tables in sql oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables that looks a bit like this.

PersonTable

| ID | Person |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |

TypeToPersonTable

| SPECID | PersonID |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 10 | 3 |

RequestSatusTable

| SPECID | StatusID |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 |

I need to calculate how many of which status id there are for each person. So the result has to look like this.

| person | status | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | good | 3 |
| name1 | bad | 2 |

I've tried using distinct like this but it's not working.

```
SELECT PersonTable.Perosn AS person, 
    (DISTINCT RequestSatusTable.StatusId) AS status,
    COUNT(RequestSatusTable.StatusId)
FROM   PersonTable
JOIN TypeToPersonTable ON PersonTable.ID = TypeToPersonTable.PersonID
JOIN RequestSatusTable ON RequestSatusTable.SPECID= TypeToPersonTable.SPECID
GROUP BY PersonTable.Person
```

I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a _set quantifier_. You can use it as `SELECT DISTINCT`, to get distinct _rows_.

Comment: Why don't you want any data for name2 and name3?

Comment: @jarlh The OP is using `INNER JOIN`s and `name2` does not have a matching row in the type table and `name3` does not have a matching row in the request table so they will both be excluded. The OP could use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include them.

Comment: @MTO, OP wrote 'for _each_ person', but excluded 2/3 of them in the result. A contradiction I wanted to clear out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `statusid` in the `GROUP BY` and use a `CASE` expression to conver the `1`/`0` of `statusid` to `good`/`bad`:

```sql
SELECT p.Person,
       CASE r.StatusId WHEN 1 THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END AS status,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM   PersonTable p
       JOIN TypeToPersonTable t
       ON p.ID = t.PersonID
       JOIN RequestSatusTable r
       ON r.SPECID= t.SPECID
GROUP BY
       p.Person,
       r.StatusId
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PersonTable (ID, Person) AS
SELECT 1, 'name1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'name2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'name3' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TypeToPersonTable (SPECID, PersonID) AS
SELECT 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE RequestSatusTable (SPECID, StatusID) AS
SELECT 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PERSON | STATUS | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | good | 3 |
| name1 | bad | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z2JRajnV)